# Python DSP, Automatic Gain Control (AGC)

Tags: python, filter, signal-processing

I'll try and ask specific questions here:-

I'm using python to look at some relatively basic DSP, and I'd like to implement Automatic Gain Control. Unless I'm mistaken this takes the (simplified) form:

[image]

I'm not too concerned by phase shifts between the i/o signals and the input signal is 1MHz sine wave modulated by a slowly varying wave (as indicated above) and I'm sampling at 40MHz. My questions are:

**(i) I'm unable to find any decent description on AGC, suggestions for this are welcome.**

[I have a very good book on [general DSP](http://www.dspguide.com/), but AGC is only mentioned in passing]

I know the basic idea of *low in-signal then high gain*, and vice versa; and I also appreciate a filter generating the 'fast attack'/'slow decay' response, but I'm unsure of details on AGC algorithms within DSP.

Secondly:

**(ii) How may I achieve this within python?** My starting code is something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# 1000 samples of a 1MHz signal, sampled at 40MHz
sample_rate = 40e6
fc          = 1e6
fm          = 1e5
nsamples    = 1000

# for now assume an AM type signal  
t = np.arange(nsamples) / sample_rate
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*fc*t) * ( (1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*fm*t))/2 )

plt.plot(t, signal)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('time (0 to 25us)')
plt.ylabel('ip signal amplitude')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such things are often modeled in Matlab and its language is pretty similar to Python. Check out in Google. You may start [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEEQFjAD&url=http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461401667-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1180039-p174121673&ei=LtcQU7McgrXgBMTdgdAI&usg=AFQjCNHUReiMDeUPA-hpYoerCXiPZLvXZg&sig2=j5UA1xMWoB-qjdelhsDpLQ&bvm=bv.62286460,d.bGE&cad=rja).
It's a free chapter from the book **Perez, Automatic Gain Control**